# The entry in MySQL database changes after some queries from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

This is a PHP code, which performs two operations, one is adding item to an array and then updating that array in MySQL and the second one is removing an item from the same array and updating the MySQL Database.
It performs some queries properly and updates the array in perfect format in database. The array looks like this **["2", "9", "4", "3", "6"]**. After some queries, it changes the format of the array and it looks like this **{"0":"2","2":"4","3":"3","4":"6"}**. (In this case, I've removed the second element from the array). Why does this happens ?? HELP !!

***PHP Code:::***

```
<?php 
$con=mysqli_connect("xxx","yyy","zzz","xyz");
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){      
    $todo = ( isset( $_GET['todo'] ) ) ? intval($_GET['todo']) : 0;
    $user_id = ( isset( $_GET['user_id'] ) ) ? intval($_GET['user_id']) : 0;
    $product_id = ( isset( $_GET['product_id'] ) ) ? $_GET['product_id'] : "0";
} else {
    echo 'Error';
}
// When the value of $todo is 1, it means Add, and when it is 2, it means remove
if($todo == 1){ //add
    $q="SELECT wishlist FROM user where user_id = '".$user_id."'";
    $query = mysqli_query($con, $q);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
        $a = '"' . $product_id . '"';
        if(strpos($row['wishlist'], $a) !== false){ //matched
            $response["error"] = true;
            $response["message"] = 'Product already in Wishlist';
            die(json_encode($response));
        } else {
            $wishlist = array();
            $wishlist = json_decode($row['wishlist'], true);
            array_push($wishlist, $product_id);
            $q1="UPDATE `user` SET `wishlist` = '".json_encode($wishlist)."' WHERE `user_id` = '".$user_id."'";
            $query1 = mysqli_query($con, $q1);          
            $response["error"] = false;
            $response["message"] = 'Product added to Wishlist';
            die(json_encode($response));
        }
    } else {
        $response["error"] = true;
        $response["message"] = 'Error 1';
        die(json_encode($response));
    }
} else if($todo == 2){ //remove
    $q2="SELECT wishlist FROM user where user_id = '".$user_id."'";
    $query2 = mysqli_query($con, $q2);
    $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query2);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($query2) > 0) {
        $a1 = '"' . $product_id . '"';
        if(strpos($row2['wishlist'], $a1) !== false){ //matched
            $wishlist1 = array();
            $wishlist1 = json_decode($row2['wishlist'], true);
            if(($key = array_search($product_id, $wishlist1)) !== false) {
                unset($wishlist1[$key]);
            }
            $q3="UPDATE `user` SET `wishlist` = '".json_encode($wishlist1)."' WHERE `user_id` = '".$user_id."'";
            $query3 = mysqli_query($con, $q3);          
            $response["error"] = false;
            $response["message"] = 'Product removed from Wishlist';
            die(json_encode($response));
        } else {
            $response["error"] = true;
            $response["message"] = 'Product does not exist in Wishlist';
            die(json_encode($response));
        }
    }
} 
else {
    $response["error"] = true;
    $response["message"] = 'Error 3';
    die(json_encode($response));    
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`unset` leaves a “hole” in the numeric array indices - so it gets converted to an object when you encode it as JSON, because that is the only way to preserve the actual key values in that case.

Use `array_values` to get a continuously numerically indexed array again, before you encode it as JSON.